# What is the difference between 'Eavesdropping' and 'Remote Spying' in ISO/IEC 27005?

Tags: iso27000

In the Annex C of ISO/IEC 27005 typical threats are described, among others eavesdropping and remote spying. When searching on the internet for further description of the two terms I found them used synonymously.

So why are the two listed separately?

Answer (score 1):

**Eavesdropping**

Reading sensitive information within a short range. In other words, eavesdropping.

For an instance, most credit cards come with a chip in their hearts. That makes it vulnerable to RFID attacks. Read this article [RFID Credit Cards and Theft](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/security/how-to/a1142/4206464/) by Joel Johnson to know more.

**Remote spying**

Monitoring a device (which is not apparently yours) in another location, regardless of the range.

All you need is to gain access to remotely control the target device. A malware or a spying software on the target machine would do the needful.

You would be surprised to know Not just attackers use this to secretly monitor other devices, a lot of legal usage of this method is around us. Employers can monitor employees devices(since most of the devices are provided by the employer) and parents can use this to monitor their children(for safety purpose, etc.)

Comment: So the ISO standard states the following: as a vulnerability: "Unprotected sensitive traffic" and as a corresponding threat "Eavesdropping", as another vulnerability "Transfer of passwords in clear" with the matching threat "Remote spying". How is range a factor there? I understand your explanation, it just doesnt seem fitting to me within the scope of the ISO 27005.

Comment: Well, my explanation may be more practical than the definitions. How would an attacker attack the unprotected sensitive traffic in a payment process (POS payment or ATM transaction using RFID cards,etc. ) from a million miles away? For an instance, to sniff a card, you definitely need range (most sniff attacks would work only within a short range/inter connected network). Kindly let us know after you have found the fitting answer, it would be helpful to some. Just curious!